# While and if statements not evaluating correctly

Tags: php, loops

EDIT: This code now works correctly, I only left it in case someone finds themselves in my situation. Thanks.

I'm facing a very strange situation with my code. I have the following:

```
$m = 0; $star = ""; $star2 = "";
while($star == "")
{
   //some stuff
   if(m1 == 0) { break; }           
   $m1 -= 1;
}
```

For some crazy reason, when I'm debugging this code it runs the while loop only once (even though `$star` is still equal to `""` and then reaches the `if` and breaks.
I have tried different approaches to no avail. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: it should probably be `if ($m1 == ...` (note the $).

Comment: What is `$m1`?  Where does `$m` get used?  Where does `$star2` get used?  You don't have a dollar sign in `if (m1 == 0)`.  Please post your actual code.

Comment: What condition are you checking with `==""`

Comment: This is one of those times when your head is blowing hot and you can't cool down to discover your problem. Thanks aioobe!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no $ before m1, so PHP will assume it's a literal string 'm1' and throw a notice error. 'm1' is then compared with 0, which is true, and your loop breaks.

You haven't initialized $m1 in your example either, so even if you used $m1, it would still break.

Make sure you have all PHP errors and warnings turned on, they are very helpful for things like this!

Comment: I didn't include the part of the code that assigns to m1. But the crazy problem was with the crazy dollar!

Comment: dollar is t3h sacred letter in php

Comment: I guess I'm just tensed. I restarted my debugger and everything is now working fine. Thanks. @andreas ??

Answer (score 1):

i guess thee is a typo in this line

```
$star2 = ""
```

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata because you edited this typo in your question / code, this correct advice no longer relates to the question.  I would like to ask you to return this typo to the question so that NarayaN's answer makes sense / has value.

Answer (score 0):

`m1` is being treated as a bare string, since there is no constant with that name. Then it is converted to an integer, giving `0`, which is of course equal to `0`. Thus your loop exits in the first iteration.

Perhaps you forgot a `$` in front of that `m1`?